# Is there a method to prevent hover on header not the navigation bar?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, navbar, anchor

Whenever I click on underneath the navbar then It shows like a link, and I don't want that. just like I shown in this picture. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUoTT.jpg

Comment: don't understand what you want... remove the underline ?

Comment: No sir, emm when I hover over underneath the header below the navbar its shows like you are on navbar and that page is underlined.

Comment: could you please display the code of your navbar when 'home' is underlined

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/i4LpAUs this is happening over my site navbar

Comment: I hope this video will help you a lot to understand what am saying

Comment: ok, i need to see your navbar code. there is a padding somewhere

Answer (score 1):

There is some css issues. like padding or hights of your navbar link elements